# iOS camera, torch intensity control

Tags: camera, iphone-4

is there a way to control the iPhone 4 torch intensity.

I did a lot of looking around and the documentation says there are only 3 states : off, on, auto. Any kind of workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a way to do this as of iOS 5.0.1.